# Strange behavior of win desktop shortcut

Tags: microsoft-windows, start-up

The emacs installer puts a shortcut on the desktop that works perfectly.

If I open the emacs/bin folder, choose emacs.exe an the "Send to desktop" it creates a different kind of shortcut. Clicking that one first opens a dos window before starting the gui and stays up until the gui quits. Its property sheet has more tabs than the one created by the installer.

These are binary files so I can't tell anything by looking inside them

Can anyone explain why the installer-created shortcut works correctly and the other does not?

Answer (score 0):

For reasons that are esoteric and dumb, on Windows you should run the `runemacs.exe` instead of `emacs.exe`. If you want more information, see [appendix H.1 How to Start Emacs on MS-Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-Startup.html)

Comment: Thank you .  .   .